# Adding a field to an existing SQLAlchemy schema that contains data

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask

Is there a way I could update my database schema without affecting my existing data?

Comment: What specific problem are you trying to overcome? Your question is rather vague and we'll be able to help you more easily if you give us some details.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two possible options: first is to manually update the database schema (`ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN foo ...`) and second option would be using some kind of [migrations tool](http://packages.python.org/alembic/).